# Fiware: subscription duration

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

what are the possiblities for the [subscription duration](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/duration/)?
I saw that the default one is "PT24H".
what is the maximum period that I can get, and can it be unlimitted for example?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NGSIv1 (i.e. `POST /v1/subscribeContext` operation) `duration` is mandatory. If you don't use an explicit value, then `PT24H` (24 hours) is used by default, as you mention. You cannot set "unlimited" explicitly, but something absurdly large (such as `P100Y`, i.e. one hundred years) would achieve the same effect from a practical point of view.

In [NGSIv2](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/) (i.e. `POST /v2/subscriptions` operation) `expires` (which value is a date) is used instead of duration. In this case, you can create subscription without `expires`.

Comment: Thanks, one more clarification about the subscription expiration please. Does the duration of the subscription is counted starting from the latest time that the broker sent a notification or from the latest time an entity published its value? and if it is counted from the latest time the broker sent a notification, does this mean that the ONTIMEINTERVAL subscription can never expired? Thanks again!

Comment: Excelent questions... for new posts :) I mean, in SOF it is not a good idea to mix the main question in the post with additional questions in comments. It is better to create new question post for them. Could you do that, please? Thanks!

Comment: yes ofcourse!Thanks! done under this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697121/fiware-when-does-the-subscription-duration-count-starts